# Api redirection according to region

Tags: java, rest, aws-lambda, devops

Our application is in two region US and EU and Our client can belong to any region.
We have a endpoint like:
US - [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
EU - eu.example.com

We have a scenario where if we call any API like
[https://www.example.com/api/v1/getDoc?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}](https://www.example.com/api/v1/getDoc?access_token=%7BACCESS_TOKEN%7D) so it will redirect request according to client region.
Suppose above access token belong to EU then the request will redirect to eu.example.com

**Solution 1**- If we use "aws lamda funtion" and one global table (Suppose Dynamo db) to check for the region of client then **it will cause latency issue if request contains multipart and base64 String.**

I need some better solution for this approach. So that we can overcome with this latency issue .
Or some other better solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of CloudFront and Route53 it is possible to build and host your system so that the end-user is always served from the geographically closest AWS region.
Please see [Choosing a routing policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html) for details on available routing policies in Route53.
Which policy is most suitable depends on the architecture of your application (i.e. do you have an active-passive setup or is your application distributed, among other criteria).

So essentially, using CloudFront (and possibly Lambda@edge) it is possible to have both the US portal ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)) and the EU portal (eu.example.com) live all over the globe, to alleviate (network) latency issues (please see [CloudFront features](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/features/) to read up on what CloudFront can do for you).

Note however that hosting a distributed application across multiple regions usually requires some proper hard thinking about architecture, and where and how you store (and possibly replicate) your data.

It is not entirely clear what your actual use-case is and what the underlying reasons and drivers are for why your users need to be divided, but that is not part of the question and therefore a topic for another question around application architecture and design, so I'll not comment on that.

In short, using Route53 and CloudFront you can redirect your users to two different URLs, but still have a nice user experience by serving both URLs from a geographically "close" location, given proper underlying application design.

Comment: Hi @Martin , Thanks for your suggestion , we are using cloundfront and lamda@Edge ... but we getting latency issue in the case of multipart request . Because firstly stream is travelling to the lamda@edge and from there it is redirecting to the specific region by checking the dynamo db . So this process is taking sometime compare to directly calling the url like eu.example.com. And we can not redirect request according to their geographical region. In Dynamo db we are keeping the record that which access token belong to which region.

Comment: There might be possibility that US belongs to US region but his account is in EU

Comment: Hi @Govind, thanks for clarifying the problem description a bit.
Is it fair to rephrase your problem like this: The client is talking to AWS in a region "close by", but the resources necessary to fulfill the request is not there?
Like I hinted at, you may want to take a step back and rethink your architecture here.  
Two main questions you should be asking yourself is a) how do I get the compute + data necessary to fulfill the request there?, or b) how do I instead (immediately) get the request to a place where the compute + data necessary to fulfill the request is located?

Comment: But a discussion about any architectural concerns (very interesting in itself) sounds more like a separate topic from the original question.